# Covalently bonding amide to glass

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

I am unfortunately not very good at chemistry, so I am having trouble figuring out where to start on this project.  I need to have some way of get some amide functional groups stuck on a substrate (most likely some glass beads or slides) so I can try to show some interactions of the amide with a molecule I am interested in.

Does anyone know of any literature that shows a good way to functionalize silica with amides?

Thanks for any help with this, I really appreciate it.

**EDIT:** I found some of [this stuff ((3-Aminopropyl)triethoxysilane)](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/440140?lang=en&region=US) in our lab.  Could I just put a glass slide in it and leave it over night?
Then maybe come back and wash acetyl chloride over it as in [this reaction?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schotten-Baumann_reaction)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ethanol solution, soaked over night of APTEOS will work.  You won't get great coverage, but it will be likely good enough for what you want to do.

The subsequent chemistry is a bit more touchy.  The problem is acid byproduct which forms ammonium salt with the amine functions that is difficult to remove.  This leaves latent acid catalyst at your surface.

You are better served forming the amide from your APTEOS and coating with that product.